# Maximum Support Hard Drive on a Dell R200 Server. Can it be increased?

Tags: hard-drive, dell

According to Dell specifications, their R200 server supports 2 x 1.0TB hard drives. Does anyone know whether it can support any larger than that (perhaps via a newer bios)?

Additionally, does anyone know what will happen in general when larger hard drives are used in servers (more than their specification) ? Will it just not boot, or something entirely different ? Is there a way to get around this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manufacturs tend to write their specifications at the time of product development or right at release and they say the largest drive supported is the largest one they actually sell through their channels at that time. They of course want you to buy their branded hard drives. At least this is what I have noticed. It should have no problem taking larger drives.

With older IDE drives back when capacity was getting beyond certain sizes, we did have drives that were beyond spec of the controllers and you either only saw only a portion of the drive or not all all when you tried to use too large of a drive.  This is not the case with newer sata drives at this time.

If for some reason the internal controller did have issues with larger drives, the only way to get around it is use a 3rd party controller card. Once in awhile, bios updates will fix/update certain issues also.

Answer (score 2):

There is no enforced limit as such - it will work with most SAS and SATA drives depending on the controller you have but you may have some issues with Dell support and they are unlikely to help you if there are any issues getting a third party 1.5\2TB drive to work with it. There are only 2 hard drive bays though so unless you opt for a PERC6e or one of the other secondary controllers that give you external drive connectivity you are limited to that.